# When a view controller is dealloc'd under ARC, are it's properties also dealloc'd if another object has a strong reference?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a mapping application that uses a peripheral slide in/slide out right hand view controller, much like the Google Maps application shown below ([source](http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/googlemapsiphone05.jpg)):

[image]

In my app, this slide out view has a `weak` `delegate` property, and I set the map view controller to be the delegate (e.g. `mapOptionsViewController.delegate = self` from inside `myMapViewController`).  I also wish to use the right hand slide in view for other sorts of information though.  E.g. displaying a menu for a restaurant that a user selects on the map, `menuViewController`.

My question is, if I swap out `mapOptionsViewController` for `menuViewController`, do I need to manually `nil` out the `mapOptionsViewController.delegate` from `myMapViewController` also?  My concern is that even if `mapOptionsViewController` is dealloc'd/disposed of when I do the switch to `menuViewController`, because `myMapViewController` still points to the old `mapOptionsViewController.delegate`, `mapOptionsViewController.delegate`'s memory will not be released from the heap.

So basically, if you have an object view controller `foo` (my map) which is the delegate for another view controller `bar` (map options), such that `bar.delegate = foo`, and then you switch out `bar` for `baz` (restaurant menu), do I need to set `bar.delegate = nil` from `foo`.  Or, will `bar` nil out `delegate` when the view controller `delegate` is contained in is dealloc'd as a result of being replaced with `baz`?

Comment: Don't think of allocations and deallocations. Think of ownership: release and retain. Strong properties do that, weak properties don't.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in this instance isn't the `strong`/`weak` distinction irrelevant, given that `bar.delegate = foo` creates a strong pointer from `foo` to `bar.delegate` (I assume?).  Even though the `delegate` property in `bar` is declared as `weak`, this doesn't change the fact that `foo` (the map) is still pointing to it strongly after we're done with `bar`, and so `bar.delegate` still hangs around in memory?

Comment: "`bar.delegate = foo` creates a strong pointer from `foo` to `bar.delegate`" - why would it? `bar.delegate` is `weak`.

Comment: Perhaps it's my understanding of weak pointers that is flawed.  My definition of weak pointer has always been "keep this as long as someone else points to it strongly".  If `bar.delegate = self`, called from within `foo` is not an example of strongly pointing to a `delegate` property that has been declared `weak` in `bar`'s class, can you provide an example of what is?

Comment: Well, maybe that's semantically equivalent, but you're overcomplicating it. `weak` references don't do reference counting. This **implies** that a strong reference is needed if you want to keep the object alive. But really the properties don't need to know about each other (as an implementation detail, they probably do, because they are automagically nulled out when their value is deallocated, but that's not to be considered/relied upon). If you have a strong and a weak pointer to an object and nothing else, then nulling the weak pointer has no effect, but nulling the strong one

Comment: will drop the reference count by one.

Answer (score 0):

> So basically, if you have an object view controller foo (my map) which is the delegate for another view controller bar (map options), such that bar.delegate = foo, and then you switch out bar for baz (restaurant menu), do I need to set bar.delegate = nil from foo. Or, will bar nil out delegate when the view controller delegate is contained in is dealloc'd as a result of being replaced with baz?

So, let's see if I understand what you're doing.

You have a `bar`, with a weak reference to a `foo`, so `bar.delegate = foo`. You must also have something else (I'll call it a `qux`) with a strong reference to the same `foo`, because otherwise your `foo` would have disappeared. Let's say the relevant property is `qux.menuThingy = foo`.

You then do `qux.menuThingy = baz`. What happens to your `bar`?

If the `qux` was the only thing with a strong reference to the `foo`, there are now no more strong references to the `foo`, so the `foo` is deallocated. Because you used a weak reference, `bar.delegate` has been automatically set to nil for you. You don't have to do it yourself.

If however there was yet another object with a strong reference to the `foo`, then the `foo` is still around and hasn't been deallocated.

Comment: close to what I was describing.  The map is a `foo` and for all intents and purposes, it sticks around the entire time the app is running.  On the right hand side is either a `bar` or a `baz`, depending on whether map options or a restaurant menu is occupying the right panel.  `bar` and `baz` should interchange repeatedly throughout the app - `bar` is destroyed to make way for `baz` and vice versa.  My question is whether we stop `bar` being completely destroyed (in terms of memory) to make way for `baz` if in `foo` we have `bar.delegate = self`.

Comment: ... i.e. because `foo` sticks around the whole time the app is running (unlike `bar` and `baz` who should be completely created/destroyed several times over) and holds a strong pointer by virtue of the call `bar.delegate = self` in `foo`.

Comment: Oh, so you're asking if `bar.delegate = foo` is enough to stop `bar` being destroyed? No, it's not. That doesn't count as a strong reference to `bar`, so the `bar` will get destroyed when there are no more strong references to it.

Answer (score 0):

In one word, no. as long as an object still have strong reference, and the last object that have a string reference to it is not deallocated, it is not deallocated. Or, you have a bug.

Also, `weak` references will be automatically zeroed when the object referencing to it is deallocated. However `assign` ones will not.

Comment: Right, so I think the critical thing I want to verify here is, if I set `bar` to `nil`, then `bar.delegate` will be `nil`ed also, even though another object `foo` had a strong pointer to it?

Comment: If you set `bar` to `nil` and it is the sole strong pointer, the object `bar` is pointing at got `dealloc`'d (i.e. no more `bar.delegate` - `bar` itself is gone). If `foo` still have strong pointers pointing at it it still stands. Those are mere pointers, not objects themselves, which resides in the heap - this is not C++.