# ARC: When is ephemeral view controller delegate memory reclaimed with weak reference

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

This is a follow up question from a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957151/when-a-view-controller-is-deallocd-under-arc-are-its-properties-also-dealloc) which may have included too much circumstantial detail.  Consider the following code:

BarViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol SomeDelegate
- (void)someCallback; // doesn't matter
@end

@interface BarViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SomeDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

BarViewController.m

```
#import "BarViewController.h"

@interface BarViewController ()

@end

@implementation BarViewController

@end
```

FooViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FooViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

FooViewController.m

```
#import "FooViewController.h"
#import "BarViewController.h"

@interface FooViewController () <SomeDelegate>
@end

@implementation FooViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BarViewController *bar = [[BarViewController alloc] init];
    // does this assignment create a "strong" reference i.e. increase retain count by 1?
    bar.delegate = self;
    // *do some useful stuff with bar.delegate here* //
    bar = nil; // is memory for bar.delegate free'd here,
    // or only after this instance of FooViewController is destroyed?
}

#pragma mark - SomeDelegate
- (void)someCallback {
// doesn't matter
}

@end
```

Imagine that `FooViewController` was the main view controller in some small application, and that `BarViewController` was just some short-lived thing, maybe designed to let the user select one of a few buttons.  `BarViewController` reports back what was selected via its delegate.

In my code above, when I set `bar` to `nil` in `FooViewController.m`, what happens to the memory that was set aside for `bar.delegate`?  On one hand, I am thinking that setting `bar` to `nil` might cause `bar.delegate` to also be set to `nil` as a part of the `bar` object being deallocated.  On the other hand, my understanding of a `weak` reference is that the memory is only released once there is no longer anybody pointing strongly to it.  So if `bar.delegate = self` creates a strong reference to `delegate` (does it?), is it possible that `bar.delegate` somehow still holds a pointer to our instance of `FooViewController`, even though `bar` is now `nil`?  Is there any potential for a memory leak here?

**Edit:**
So the way I'm thinking about this is, `UIWindow` would point strongly to our instance of `FooViewController` as the root view controller, and our instance of BarViewController would point weakly to our instance of `FooViewController` as its delegate.  So even when we set `bar = nil`, `bar.delegate` weakly points to an object that still has at least one strong pointer coming from `UIWindow`, so `bar.delegate` can't be free'd based on the "a weak property is freed when nobody else points strongly to it" premise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got things almost right except for here:

> On the other hand, my understanding of a weak reference is that the
>   memory is only released once there is no longer anybody pointing
>   strongly to it. So if bar.delegate = self creates a strong reference
>   to delegate (does it?)

A property declared `weak` is much simpler than you suppose.  It's just like `assign`, except the arc-generated dealloc it's class sets it to nil.  And, `bar.delegate = self`; does not "create a strong reference to delegate", it just assigns a pointer to a Foo instance that will be wiped out when Bar is deallocated.

So here's what happens:

```
// no bar exists
BarViewController *bar = [[BarViewController alloc] init];

// now a bar exists with only a stack variable referring to it, it will be released
// by arc at the bottom of this method

// YOUR QUESTION: does this assignment create a "strong" reference i.e. increase retain count by 1
bar.delegate = self;

// Answer - No. No change in retain counts.  Bar now has an assigned pointer to the
// Foo instance (self)

// *do some useful stuff with bar.delegate here* //
bar = nil; // is memory for bar.delegate free'd here,

// bar is free'd here, and would have been whether or not you set it to nil
// moreover - bar's delegate is set to nil because it was declared weak.
```

[Here's a decent Apple doc on the subject.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BarViewController *bar = [[BarViewController alloc] init];
    // does this assignment create a "strong" reference i.e. increase retain count by 1?
```

NO, you set the delegate as weak so the compiler will not strongly point to any object (in this case SELF) when bar.delegate is assigned.

bar is a local variable so it will automatically retain the BarViewController object as long as the functions does not return (increasing the count by 1 when assigned and deleting it when the function ends), or as long as you dont set it to NIL.

If you do not specify the delegate var to be weak, then yes, you will increase the retain count to SELF by 1 and you might end up with retain cycle. That is way delegates should always be weak.

```
bar.delegate = self; 
//do some useful stuff with bar.delegate here
bar = nil; // is memory for bar.delegate free'd here,
// or only after this instance of FooViewController is destroyed?
}
```

In this case, setting bar to nil will free the space in memory related to the variable bar, which is the only one pointing to the BarViewController object so yes, after that happens BarViewController will also be released, but remember that you don't have to do this because ARC will automatically set the local var to nil when function ends.

All of this is under ARC. Again, is a good convention to have the delegate pointer weak as you are doing it in your code to avoid possible retain cycles.